# Writing tests for serverless framework using Typescript and Jest is throwing "Cannot find module" error

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework, ts-jest

I am building a serverless API on AWS using serverless framework. I have set up the project using typescript template. The default project comes with a simple hello handler/ lambda function. Now I am trying to write tests for that handler. So I started installing jest.

So I created a jest.config.js file with the following content right inside the project's root folder.

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: "node",
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    },
};
```

Here is the hello handler inside the src/functions/hello.handler.ts

```
import {formatJSONResponse, ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent} from '@libs/api-gateway';
import { middyfy } from '@libs/lambda';

import schema from './schema';

const hello: ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent<typeof schema> = async (event) => {
  return formatJSONResponse({
    message: `Hello ${event.body.name}, welcome to the exciting Serverless world!`,
    event,
  });
};

export const main = middyfy(hello);
```

Then I created a src/tests directory and created a file called hello.spec.ts inside that directory with the following code.

```
import {main} from "@functions/hello/handler";
import {Context} from "aws-lambda";

describe("hello", () => {
    it("should return greeting message", async () => {
        const eventMock = {
            body: {
                name: 'John',
            },
            // Add other necessary properties for your event
            path: '/test',
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            multiValueHeaders: {},
            isBase64Encoded: false,
            pathParameters: null,
            queryStringParameters: null,
            multiValueQueryStringParameters: null,
            requestContext: null,
            resource: '',
            stageVariables: null,
            rawBody: JSON.stringify({ name: 'John' }), // Add rawBody property
        };

        const mockedContext: Context = {
            callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: false,
            functionName: 'mocked',
            functionVersion: 'mocked',
            invokedFunctionArn: 'mocked',
            memoryLimitInMB: 'mocked',
            awsRequestId: 'mocked',
            logGroupName: 'mocked',
            logStreamName: 'mocked',
            getRemainingTimeInMillis(): number {
                return 999;
            },
            done(): void {
                return;
            },
            fail(): void {
                return;
            },
            succeed(): void {
                return;
            }
        };

        // Invoke the Lambda function
        const result = await main(eventMock, mockedContext, () => {});

        console.log(result);
    })
})
```

Here is the tsconfig.paths.json file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@functions/*": ["src/functions/*"],
      "@libs/*": ["src/libs/*"],
      "@models/*": ["src/models/*"],
      "@services/*": ["src/services/*"],
      "@tests/*": ["src/tests/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

Then I run the tests using this command.

```
jest --config=jest.config.js
```

And I am getting this error.

```
FAIL  src/tests/hello.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@functions/hello/handler' from 'src/tests/hello.spec.ts'

    > 1 | import {main} from "@functions/hello/handler";
        | ^
      2 | import {Context} from "aws-lambda";
      3 |
      4 | describe("hello", () => {

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
```

What is wrong with my set up and how can I fix it?

Comment: Had a little play with this locally and the best thing I found to do was to rename the hello.handler.ts file to just hello.ts. The inclusion of .handler.ts seems to break the transform for me. Also noticed your jest config was looking for .tsx, you may just want to set this to .ts. Hopefully renaming is an option? From my perspective, i'd assume everything in the functions dir is a handler, so the extra description probably isnt needed?

Answer (score 0):

To use paths with jest you need to specify them in the jest config

```js
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: "node",
    moduleNameMapper: {
      '@functions/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/functions/$1',
      '@libs/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/libs/$1',
      '@models/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/models/$1',
      '@services/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/services/$1',
      '@tests/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/tests/$1',
    },
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    },
};
```